# Import python from wsgi fails

Tags: python, apache2, flask, mod-wsgi

I've got a folder structure on an apache2/flask server that is this:

```
/var/www/myapp
/var/www/myapp/routing.py
/var/www/myapp/__init__.py
/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi
```

My application file (routing.py) in in myapp and is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def welkom():
    return render_template('welkom.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = 'True'
    app.run()
```

My myapp.wsgi that is in wsgi-scripts is this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/myapp')
from myapp import routing as application
```

However when I load the page this is in my logs:

```
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] mod_wsgi (pid=23574): Target WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] mod_wsgi (pid=23574): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi'.
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11]   File "/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11]     import myapp.routing as application
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] ImportError: No module named myapp.routing
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] mod_wsgi (pid=23575): Target WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] mod_wsgi (pid=23575): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi'.
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11]   File "/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11]     import myapp.routing as application
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:32 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] ImportError: No module named myapp.routing
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] mod_wsgi (pid=23577): Target WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] mod_wsgi (pid=23577): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi'.
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11]   File "/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11]     import myapp.routing as application
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] ImportError: No module named myapp.routing
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] mod_wsgi (pid=23573): Target WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] mod_wsgi (pid=23573): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi'.
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11]   File "/var/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11]     import myapp.routing as application
[Fri Mar 15 08:06:33 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] ImportError: No module named myapp.routing
```

WSGI is working correctly, I verified that with a testapp. What is going wrong?

Comment: I believe your file should be `__init__.py` and not `init.py` and your path should be `/var/www/`. Alternatively you can still use `/var/www/myapp/` (and forget the part about `__init__.py`), but you must import only `routing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you intend to import a module `routing` from package `myapp` and call it as `application`.

1. That is not matching your structure. If you have `/var/www/myapp` in your path, you have to directly import the module `routing`.
2. An application is not a module, it is a callable defined in the module. It seems you'll have to do something like

   ```
   def theapp(<don't remember the argumets by heart>):
       app.debug = 'True'
       app.run()
   ```

   and then the wsgi script can do

   ```
   from routing import theapp as application
   ```

   But maybe I'm wrong here and you just have to do

   ```
   from routing import app as application
   ```

   as I have no experience with Flask.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem, solved it with the following snippet:

```
ALLDIRS = ['/var/www/MarkerDB/']

import sys 
import site 

# Remember original sys.path.
prev_sys_path = list(sys.path) 

# Add each new site-packages directory.
for directory in ALLDIRS:
  site.addsitedir(directory)

# Reorder sys.path so new directories at the front.
new_sys_path = [] 
for item in list(sys.path): 
    if item not in prev_sys_path: 
        new_sys_path.append(item) 
        sys.path.remove(item) 
sys.path[:0] = new_sys_pat
```

Source: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments#Application_Environments